# Folding elements into values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a need to fold an unbounded PCollection of key-value elements into per-key aggregates (outputting the aggregate after each input has been applied). It's important that the values be folded in the correct order, and it doesn't seem like that's supported by custom combiners. The per-key throughput will be quite low, but the overall throughput will be very high. Is there a way for me to do this in Dataflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, combiners are unordered. This is because unordered combining makes a lot of sense in the Beam model which allows late data (what would you like the behavior to be in your case, in case late data arrives?), and because it admits a very efficient implementation, and in most cases it is all that's needed.

One way you can address this for your case, sacrificing some efficiency, is implement a custom CombineFn, where:

- The accumulator, as well as the output type, is "list of input elements sorted by timestamp".
- Inserting an element into the accumulator inserts it into the sorted list
- Merging two accumulators merges the sorted lists.
- Extracting output from the accumulator is the identity function.

Basically you'll be using Combine to maintain a sorted list of values for each key, and you'll get a `PCollection<KV<K, List<V>>>`, to which you can apply a `ParDo` with your fold.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but the state would keep growing over time – I was hoping for a solution where I only needed to keep the aggregated state around.

Comment: I think for my use case it's okay to apply events in processing time order – so I wouldn't have to allow lateness, since late events would just go in the window that's open at the time it's received, right?

Comment: So: given the upcoming State API (BTW is that coming soon? :-D) I would be able to have a ParDo that keeps the current state per key in a global window and simply applies events as they come in... unless there's no ordering there, either, in which case I'd have to (I think) 1) keep fixed time windows based on processing time; 2) GroupByKey; 3) put into a new global window; and 4) have the ParDo sort and apply the events. I think.

Comment: State API is coming pretty soon, yes, and it will definitely help your use case. I'm not sure what you mean by ordering there. State API does not introduce or require any additional ordering guarantees compared to the rest of the Beam model.

Comment: I see what you mean.